# xmonad: focus window when mouse is moved

Tags: linux, xmonad, haskell

In my xmonad config, I have set `focusFollowsMouse=true` so that a window is focused when the mouse pointer is moved onto it. However, I would *also* like a window to become focused when the mouse pointer is *already* on it, and it is moved.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Move the mouse pointer over some window.
2. Focus a different window using the keyboard, e.g. by Mod+Tab or selecting a different screen.
3. Move the mouse pointer slightly, so that it stays on the same window.

Desired behavior:

The window becomes focused again.

Actual behavior:

Focus does not change.

Is there any way I can achieve the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this can be done with: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.13/docs/XMonad-Actions-UpdateFocus.html

To enable it you need to add the `focusOnMouseMove` event handler:

```
import XMonad.Actions.UpdateFocus
xmonad $ def {
  ..
  startupHook = adjustEventInput
  handleEventHook = focusOnMouseMove
  ..
}
```

Comment: An answer cannot be just a link, it has to stand on its own, for instance by summarizing the page linked.

Comment: Thanks! From the description it sounds like just the thing. I tried it but unfortunately no effect. Will check back if I get it to work.

Comment: Filed bug report: https://github.com/xmonad/xmonad-contrib/issues/210