# xmonad: mouse hover hook

Tags: xmonad, mouse-cursor, window-focus, haskell

I'm trying to make xmonad focus the window underneath the pointer when the mouse is moved, regardless of which window is focused. This was addressed in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1075571/xmonad-focus-window-when-mouse-is-moved); however, the provided solution suggests using `XMonad.Actions.UpdateFocus` which doesn't work. I decided I would just rewrite the functionality of `UpdateFocus`, but I'm not sure how to get a mouse movement/hover hook to do that.

I did some experimentation on my own, and I discovered that MotionEvents aren't being passed to the eventHook if the mouse is over a window that is interested in its own mouse events. Examples of such windows include gnome-terminal and nautilus. There is a [mailing list thread](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/xmonad/2009-November/009207.html) discussing this problem. Here was the code I used for the experimentation.

```
focusOnMouseMove :: Event -> X All
focusOnMouseMove (MotionEvent { ev_x = x, ev_y = y, ev_window = root }) = do
    return (debugPrint ((show x) ++ " " ++ (show y)) (All True))

-- later in my config

    rootMask = rootMask defaultConfig .|. pointerMotionMask,
    clientMask = clientMask defaultConfig .|. pointerMotionMask,
    startupHook = adjustEventInput,
    handleEventHook = myEventHook,
```